# React.js animate slide height when using adaptiveHeight

Tags: css, reactjs, react-slick

Is there any way to animate the slide height when using `adaptiveHeight`? For example, when you click 'next' and the next slide is taller, it would smoothly animate to the increased height.

Answer (score 3):

**Update.** I found the solution

```
.slick-list 
{
    -webkit-transition: height 250ms linear;
}
```